# Copy JSON files to local from AWS S3 bucket in windows system using CLI

Tags: json, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

Hi I'm unable to copy JSON files from S3 to local using the following command in windows.

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket// ./ --recursive
```

I'm getting the following error:

> download failed:
>   s3://availdump/apps_dumps/cashup/dump/apps/query_1111286326_2019-10-21T13:22:25.525520.json
>   to .\query_1111286326_2019-10-21T13:22:25.525520.json [Errno 22]
>   Invalid argument:
>   'C:\Users\gaura\Downloads\city_wise_collection_summary_(April -
>   July)\apps_dumps\query_1111286326_2019-10-21T13:22:25.525520.json.4A2aA011'

NOte: I'm getting this error only for JSON files, text files are copying fine

Answer (score 0):

Edited: the ":" in the file names is probably the problem , windows doesn't allow : in filenames.

Comment: This doesn't work, I get the same error as mentioned above. I'm guessing its a problem with downloading JSON files on a windows system

Comment: Oh , just noticed - remove the : from the file names - they are reserved character in windows:

Comment: how do we that? the files are in S3, there are thousands of files that i have to download

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is ":" in file name. It's not compatible with windows.

> -21T13:22:25.525520.json [Errno 22]

My solution: install WSL for windows. This will give you access to a "linux" kernel in windows. Configure AWS cli as usual from WSL. Then run you command as before from wsl.